# JSON Object is only showing the first key, ignoring the rest

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I've never had this happen before, but the below example shows the JSON structure, however it is only returning the length as 1 and will not show any objects after 0.

I really have no idea what's wrong here and hoping someone sees something I don't. Thank you in advance!

[image: JSON Example]

For what it's worth, here's the code:

```
        var count = Object.keys(r.tasks).length;
        var i = 0;
        $.each(r.tasks[userid],function(k,v){
          var day = new Date(v.day);
          var data = {
            id: k,
            d: day,
            taskID: parseInt(v.task_id),
            location: v.location,
            address: v.address,
            blurb: v.blurb,
            prettyDate: v.pretty_date,
            techStatus: v.tech_status,
            tags: v.all_tags,
            taskTotal: v.task_total
          };
          returnTasks.push(data);
          i++;
          if(i == count){
            loadDay(returnTasks);
          }
        });


        function loadDay(events){
          console.log(events);
          console.log(events.length);
        }
```

Comment: json ... object ... length? please add real data.

Comment: need to see the code.  probably some typo.

Comment: what's `myTasks`? Did you mean to log `events`?

Comment: Added in the code @ShakilAhmed ... doesn't matter what I do, it won't loop through anything past the 1st object.

Comment: @chazsolo, yeah that was supposed to be events. Tried to simplify the code for posting.

Comment: What is `count`?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, again I'm trying to post just the code needed. Count is what I'm using to check to see if the loop has finished. Added it in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `count` to the wrong length. You're looping through `r.tasks[userid]`, but you're setting it to the number of properties in `r.tasks` (i.e. the number of different users, not the number of tasks for this user). It should be:

```
var count = Object.keys(r.tasks[userid]).length;
```

If `r.tasks[userid]` is an array, you don't need to use `Object.keys()`, just use

```
var count = r.tasks[userid].length;
```

You also don't need the `i` variable in this case, since `k` will be the array index.